# How to insert rows in Qt model that may not happen?

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QAbstractItemModel's `beginInsertRows()` and `endInsertRows()` to insert rows to my underlying data store. I call the data insert function between the begin and end methods. However, the insert function in my data returns a bool parameter which indicates the insert may fail due to data restrictions. If the insert fails, the model and its associated views should not change. If this happens, how to let the model know not to insert rows or stop to insert rows?

Comment: You have to differentiate between internal and external modification of the model: Internal means that your internal data representation has been changed and the model has to notify the views about that. External means that a view wants to modify the model, which by itself has to react on these changes and thus modify the underlying data representation. Which scenario are we talking about?

Comment: My case is like that: I insert a named item input by a dialog. If the same name is already used. The insert will fail. The insert results should show in views if succeed.

Answer (score 3):

I assume, you are using a custom model, which inherits `QAbstractItemModel`. In that case, you can write insert method:

```
bool CustomModel::insertMyItem(const MyItemStruct &i)
{
    if (alredyHave(i))
        return false;
    beginInsertRow();
    m_ItemList.insert(i);
    endInsertRow();
}
```

You data method would be something like this:

```
QVariant CustomModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole || role == Qt::ToolTipRole)
    switch (index.column())
    {
        case INDEX_ID:
            return m_ItemList[index.row()].id;
        case INDEX_NAME:
            return m_ItemList[index.row()].name;
        ...
    }
    return QVariant();
}
```

And, finally, you input method would be:

```
void MainWindow::input()
{
    MyInputDialog dialog(this);
    if (dialog.exec() == QDialog::Rejected)
        return;
    myModel->insertMyItem(dialog.item());
}
```